# Using image sprite with an Image control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to use sprites with WPF and am having some trouble.  The entire sprite size is width=100 height=1754.  The first image starts at 0,0 and the icons are all 32x32. So far I have this but the image is not rendering at all

```
<UserControl x:Class="Exemplify.Word.Addin.Presentation.ImageTestUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="SpriteImage" UriSource="Assets/sprites2.png"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Name="Test">
        <Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="{StaticResource SpriteImage}">
            <Image.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="100, 1754, 32, 32"></RectangleGeometry>
            </Image.Clip>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="-100" Y="1754">

                </TranslateTransform>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where is the reason to use sprite in the desktop application?

Comment: I don't want to have to cut up 100s of images just to implement them individually on numerous xaml controls. Also, when the images are update I simply update one image (sprite.png) instead of slicing up the sprite again and then updating each updated control image individually.  From the posts in SO this is not uncommon using xaml. Can you offer any advice?

Comment: There is an even more simple solution to this question here: [Crop an Image in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201128/crop-an-image-in-wpf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a `CroppedBitmap` as the `Source` of your image. For example to cut out the second image in the third row (at x=32, y=64) you would write:

```
<Image Height="32" Width="32">
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="{StaticResource SpriteImage}"
                       SourceRect="32,64,32,32"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Or use a Rectangle with an `ImageBrush` instead of an `Image` control, where you could set the `Viewbox`:

```
<Rectangle Height="32" Width="32">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource SpriteImage}"
                    ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="32,64,32,32"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Clemens excellent answer, which I upvoted, here is a way to do the OnMouseOver.

```
<Rectangle Height="58" Width="375">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style>                         
            <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image8.png" Viewbox="0,0,1,.5"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Rectangle.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>                          
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image8.png" Viewbox="0,.5,1,.5"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```