# Clipping image in Windows Store app

Tags: image, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

So exactly how do we do **sprites** in UWP a.k.a. Windows Store apps? The two methods described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471928/using-image-sprite-with-an-image-control-wpf-xaml) do not work in UWP. (`CroppedBitmap` class doesn't work and `ImageBrush` class doesn't have `Viewbox` property). I tried doing `Clip` with `RenderTransform` but haven't succeeded with that either. Where to go next?

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're actually trying to do? By sprites, I'm guessing that you want a single large bitmap that contains all the sprite images in all states and then trying to change clipping dynamically to perform animation of the sprite. If this is indeed what you're trying to do then I'd suggest investigating [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) which is much more targeted at what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: @ibebbs: Your understanding is correct. In WPF and SL we can do this in pure XAML without writing any code at all (see the SO link I posted in the question). I already saw Win2D while googling. Looks like I'll have to use that as final resort if I don't find an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ibebbs said, **[Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D)** is a good choice for using sprites in UWP. Win2D is an easy-to-use Windows Runtime API for immediate mode 2D graphics rendering with GPU acceleration. And [**CanvasSpriteBatch Class**](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteBatch.htm) in Win2D is optimized for sprites scenario.

**CanvasSpriteBatch** allows multiple bitmaps to be drawn more efficiently and has better performance than [DrawImage](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_DrawImage.htm) API, especially if many sprites are drawn in a row using the same source bitmap. **CanvasSpriteBatch** supports the following features:

- Sprites can be drawn with their own position, scale, rotation and tint ([Draw Overload](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteBatch_Draw.htm) and [DrawFromSpriteSheet Overload](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteBatch_DrawFromSpriteSheet.htm))
- Individual sprites may be flipped horizontally or vertically. ([CanvasSpriteFlip](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteFlip.htm))
- Sprite Sheets ([DrawFromSpriteSheet Overload](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Overload_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteBatch_DrawFromSpriteSheet.htm))
- Sprites can be [clamped to a source rectangle](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteOptions.htm), removing the need to add padding between sprites in a sprite sheet.
- Batches can be [sorted by bitmap](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteSortMode.htm) for better performance.

For more info about how to use CanvasSpriteBatch, please see [CanvasSpriteBatch Class document](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasSpriteBatch.htm) and also [Sprite Sheets sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/ExampleGallery/UAP/SpriteSheets) on GitHub.

**Update:**

If you do not want to use Win2D, one simple way to achive what you want is using **[ImageBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.aspx)** with **[Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.brush.transform.aspx)** like following:

```
<Rectangle Width="128" Height="192">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush AlignmentX="Left"
                    AlignmentY="Top"
                    ImageSource="Assets/WizardIdleRight.png"
                    Stretch="None">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="SpriteSheetOffset" X="0" Y="-384" />
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Here I used the [WizardIdleRight.png](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/UAP/SpriteSheets/WizardIdleRight.png) in [Sprite Sheets sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/ExampleGallery/UAP/SpriteSheets), we can change the offset in **[TranslateTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.translatetransform.aspx)** to show the sprite we want.

Comment: Thanks Jay, very informative. The game I'm developing is a simple cards game, where I have all the 52 card images in a single png. What I was looking for was to load this image as an application level resource and then assign set `Clip` property of each `Image` element to show corresponding card. Win2D sound to me like a bigger gun for more intense, interactive and real-time games. Or is it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you're writing this in XAML why not DataTemplate the cards and use graphic resources for just the suit glyphs (or better yet, a symbol font). This would result in much smaller size application which scales better across various resolutions.

Comment: @dotNET If you do not want to use Win2D, using ImageBrush with Transform may be one easy way. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Nice one. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.