# WPF zoom or scale sprite image

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, sprite

Is it possible to zoom or scale a sprite image in a Windows Presentation Foundation app?

I am new to building WPF apps and have just been playing around so far.

I am trying to implement a playing card based game, which I originally had working in PHP. In that I use the css `zoom` and `scale` properties to change the card size depending on the screen resolution.

Thanks to snippets of code on here, I managed to get my sprite working:

```
<Rectangle Width="300" Height="415">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Deck.png" 
            Stretch="None"
            AlignmentX="Left" 
            AlignmentY="Top"
            ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,415,0,0"  />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle Width="300" Height="415">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Deck.png" 
            Stretch="None"
            AlignmentX="Left" 
            AlignmentY="Top"
            ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,830,0,0" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

I can't see how to change the size though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ViewBoxes with zero width and height look odd. Sure that it actually works? That said, try some other Stretch value. As a general hint, thoroughly read the [TileBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.tilebrush?view=netframework-4.7.2) online documentation first.

Comment: You may also use an Image element with a CroppedBitmap, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22475123/1136211

Comment: I couldn't change the dimensions on the Rectangle without affecting what part of the sprite is shown. But using the Image with CroppedBitmap worked for me. Many thanks,